# Delphi 2010 errors open SysUtils

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

My problem is that when i get an error in Delphi 2010, it doesn´t show me where or in which line the error was created, it only opens a new page SysUtils which doesn´t tell me anything.
How can i stop Delphi from opening SysUtils and configure it to show me the error line?

I really don't know much about Delphi configurations.

Comment: Try to find and check (or uncheck?) 'Use debug DCU's' in Project/Compiler options.

Comment: Please be more clear. "when I get an error" doesn't tell us anything. Do you mean a compiler error? A runtime error? An access violation? A wavy red underline in the IDE? An error in the Structure panel? When you type "an error", the **very** next thing you should do is give us the type of error and the *exact* error message you're getting, including any memory addresses. Giving us the information to work with makes it much more likely you'll get a quick solution to your problem. :-)

Comment: Sorry about the error, it was a compiler error i think, i really dont know how to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taken to SysUtils by the IDE, this is typically because the problem is in the core compiler internals, and there is no source that it can show you.

It may be worth enabling "debug DCUs" in the compiler and doing a build, as that may allow more information to be shown.

Comment: Actually i had to disable "debug DCUs" and it solved my problem, thank you, and thanks Sertac Akyuz for the same answere.